# The fastest way to get the LayoutInflater

Tags: java, android, layout-inflater

I can get the LayoutInflater with:

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

or

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

**Which way is faster and recommended?**

Comment: you can easily find what one is faster by timing them

Comment: How many times do you intend to get a new `LayoutInflater` that this matters? FWIW [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) says to use the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

The second version will be (marginally) faster, as the first version involves a method lookup (see code below). For the sake of clarity/maintainability the first version is preferable.

```
    /**
     * Obtains the LayoutInflater from the given context.
     */
    public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (LayoutInflater == null) {
            throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
        }
        return LayoutInflater;
    }
```

Reference: [LayoutInflator.java](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the answer to this question but i can suggest a way to find out. You should profile these methods and see for yourself which one is fastest in execution.

You could do this:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
```

Run it a few time and write down or save the returned time and then run the other function to see wich one preforms fastest

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
long endTime = System.nanoTime();
long duration = (endTime - startTime);  //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
```

Now you know how to profile any method you want, to see which one is faster in execution!